# Use result of `npm show <package> version` as argument in another npm script

Tags: npm

The result of `npm show <package> version` is something like `3.1.2`. How can I pass this result into another npm script as an argument?

```json
    "scripts": {
        "some-script": "node index.js <3.1.2>"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For npm v6 and below, use [the `npm_package_*` environment variables](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars):

> The package.json fields are tacked onto the `npm_package_` prefix. So, for instance, if you had `{"name":"foo", "version":"1.2.5"}` in your package.json file, then your package scripts would have the `npm_package_name` environment variable set to `"foo"`, and the `npm_package_version` set to `"1.2.5"`. You can access these variables in your code with `process.env.npm_package_name` and `process.env.npm_package_version`, and so on for other fields.

In particular, you want the `npm_package_version` environment variable, which you can get with `process.env.npm_package_version`.

Note that for lifecycle scripts in npm v7, `npm_package_version` is still available, but most other such environment variables have been changed to be accessible via a different method according to [NPM RFC 21](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md), but `npm_package_version` is one that is preserved (you can still use the above shown method)

> In addition to these, the following environment variables will be preserved from npm v6's set, in order to provide an easier upgrade path:
>
> - `npm_package_name`
> - `npm_package_version`
> - [...]